# How can I decode the emitted event data field using Foundry Cast in Ethereum?

Tags: events, foundry, data, cast

I'm trying to extract relevant information from the event but I'm not sure how to decode the emitted event data using [cast](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/). Any tips or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

E.g for this [tx](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5d67b7197993fca532f9b9edd7775b55400645b78304bc6eeb103234ad09f768#eventlog) how can we decode the data and topics from their hex value using cast

Answer (score 2):

My approach for decoding data and topics for above example tx with the use of cast:

1. Type `cast receipt 0x5d67b7197993fca532f9b9edd7775b55400645b78304bc6eeb103234ad09f768 logs --rpc-url YOUR_MAINNET_RPC_URL`

[image]

2. From the above output take from the first topic (0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef) first 4 bytes (with 0x - 0xddf252ad). Next type `cast 4byte 0xddf252ad` . This command will returns event signature:

[image]

3. Type `cast 4byte-decode 0xddf252ad000000000000000000000000164c58b3fb3175a8b78034d0723f8bfc0066bc6d000000000000000000000000972e06d1c62e91884067aedba10bbbe792f9d22d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004a817c800` . This command will returns event signature with decoded values:

[image]

**Explanation**:

(**0xddf252ad** (First 4 bytes from the first topic) **+**

**0x000000000000000000000000164c58b3fb3175a8b78034d0723f8bfc0066bc6d** (second topic - first address argument) **+**

**0x000000000000000000000000972e06d1c62e91884067aedba10bbbe792f9d22d** (third topic - second address argument) **+**

**0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004a817c800** (from the "data" field (first screen) - third uint256 argument)